# Why was my question closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

[Why is fluorine a oxidising agent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110757/why-is-fluorine-a-oxidising-agent#)

No reason was giving for closing the question, to me the questions seems quite clear.

And also in the future I request the mods to provide appropriate reason for closing questions.

Answer (score 4):

> Why was my question closed?

Probably because you have three questions in one, although in your question they are related and I don't really consider that a problem, thus I would be open to reopening in this case.

> No reason was giving for closing the question

Technically, the close reason is already provided to you (it's the large box above your question). Whether you agree with it is a different (although equally valid) matter.

> to me the questions seems quite clear

The close reason doesn't say it was unclear, so that wasn't really the point.

> I request the mods

If you mean [*diamond mods*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), then with all due respect I must say no, because a lot of closed questions aren’t closed by us (including yours), and we unfortunately can’t provide reasons for literally everyone else’s close votes.

Comment: The box says question is not focused, and moreover they are not three different question, they are three different reasons why fluorine shouldn't be a oxidising agent. By mod I'm referring to whoever closed my question , i feel the reason given for closure is really vague. Kindly consider reopening it

Comment: You quite literally have a list, saying "My questions", with three numbered bullet points underneath, and you're telling me it's not three questions? I *did* say they were related, though.